# R: How to convert date with %b for different languages

Tags: r, timezone

I am new to R and I am having trouble to convert a date. Consider the following:

```
> A <- '30-Abr-17' #Portuguese
> B <- '30-Apr-17' #English
> as.POSIXct(A, '%d-%b-%y', tz = '')
[1] "2017-04-30 -03"
> as.POSIXct(B, '%d-%b-%y', tz = '')
[1] NA
```

When I use

```
tz = ''
```

It uses my timezone that is:

```
> Sys.timezone()
[1] "America/Sao_Paulo"
```

I tried something like:

```
as.POSIXct(B, '%d-%b-%y', tz = 'America/New_York')
[1] NA
```

But it still did not work. Any insights?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`?as.POSIXct` gives:

> If format is specified, remember that some of the format
>   specifications are locale-specific, and you may need to set the
>   LC_TIME category appropriately via Sys.setlocale. This most often
>   affects the use of %b, %B (month names) and %p (AM/PM).

Try to call `Sys.setlocale()` before using `%b`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I added   Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME",'us') and then came back to  Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME",""). It worked properly.